# How to add headers in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, header, http-headers

I'm running a JSF 2.3 Java EE 8 web application. How Can I add html headers like: `""X-XSS-Protection" HTTP header with "1; mode=block"`

Application server is glassfish 5.0.

Comment: @Selaron I use JSF facelets pages (.xhtml),  don't work with servlet (HttpServletResponse ) . Plus I don't want to apply this for every .xhtml page. I need something to apply in web.xml or in the admin console of glassfish. So no NOT a duplicate

Comment: Filters work perfectly fine together with JSF and they are configureable in web.xml.

Comment: @BalusC do you have an example? so there is no way to do this in glassfish admin console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info